# Error: "'str' object is not callable" on any use of Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to write some Tests in Selenium and since many elements do not have ID or NAME i tried to use Xpath. However, no matter what, whenever I use Xpath i get the same Error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Following is the most simple Example I tested it on which resulted in the same Error.

Here is the Code in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('cannot_share_this_link/index.php')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[@id='sign']"))
```

Tested on:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Comtest
        </title>
        <script src="comajax.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div>
         <br>
         <input type="button" id="sign" value="Sign up" onclick="window.open('signup.php','popUpWindow','height=500,width=800,left=700,top=300,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
         <br>
         <input type="button" id="log" value="Log in" onclick="window.open('login.php','popUpWindow','height=500,width=800,left=700,top=300,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: I would like to note that this question is not a duplicate as the linked thread is apparently looking for a string as output while i am looking for an element. Also the methods shown there two years ago throw deprecation warnings nowadays if they even work at all (Since i can't get it to work at all i couldn't tell).
I have read the linked thread, i have stumbled upon it around 30 times during my search for a solution. There probably isn't a thread about this issue i haven't read, otherwise i wouldn't be posting.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[@id='sign']"))
```

use this :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sign']")
```

Internal method signature :

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
```

It is expected to use By then separated with comma  and then value.

value could be your xpath, in case if By is xpath that you are supplying.

I would advise to induce `Explicit wait (WebDriverWait)`

**Code trial :**

```
sign_in_ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sign']")))
sign_in_ele.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I have tried that already, when i use that it shows that  "sign" in "//*[@id='sign']" is a synthax error. Just tried it again.

Comment: Did you try this `sign_in_ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sign']")))`

Comment: Yes, in the actual program and on all the sites i tested it on i have appropriate waits. There is none here since the site loads immediately. I always test that with id-based waits.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[@id='sign']"))
```

With:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign"]'))
```

Comment: When i try to use that i get the deprecation error:
/home/install/PycharmProjects/Comtest/main.py:10: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign"]')

Comment: That's a warning, but does it run?

Comment: I tried with a .click() but it doesn't happen.